# Yellow triangle frame marker in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image: Yellow triangle]

This is a lame question but, what is this yellow triangle marking a frame? I was trying out different shortcuts and I think I accidentally added it. I can't find it in the Blender docs.

The only reason I'm asking is because I'm having an audio sync issue when I render my video and I'm trying to hunt down the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is just a marker. You can add it by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> and delete by selecting it and pressing <kbd>X</kbd>

If you can't select it, uncheck *Lock Markers* option in the Marker menu.

[image]

You can find more info about the markers in Blender Manual:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/animation/markers.html